# How to save window resources

Tags: wpf, vb.net

In my application I'm creating a style like this:

```
Dim ButtonStyle as new Style(GetType(Button))
ButtonStyle.Setters.Add(New Setter(BackgroundProperty,Brushes.Gray))
Resources.Add("ButtonStyle", ButtonsStyle)
```

And I would like to save this style when the application exits so that when the application runs next time it would load my new style. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In c# sorry :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Settings.Default.Resources))
        {
            Style buttonStyle = new Style(typeof(Button));
            buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red));
            Resources.Add(typeof(Button), buttonStyle);
        }
        else
            Resources = XamlReader.Parse(Settings.Default.Resources) as ResourceDictionary;
    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnExit(e);

        // Save styles
        Settings.Default.Resources = XamlWriter.Save(Resources);
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```